# Child element (tooltip to an image) is clipped inside a parent div which has fixed width and overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, tooltip

I have a parent div with fixed width with overflow hidden. The parent div has several images which I scroll using custom Javascript. For each image I have a tooltip which I want to show when I mouseover the images. The tooltips are big and are clipped when I mouseover the images since the parent div has overflow hidden. What is the best solution to this problem. I have been looking around a lot and haven't found a single feasible solution.

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If something's inside an "overflow: hidden" `<div>`, then it'll be clipped; that's what the style property means. The only thing you can do is place the tooltip element absolutely as a child of the `<body>` or something.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to that tooltip elements will be children of the BODY, so they won't be clipped.
In order to display the tooltip in a position relative to the image, you will have to know the position of the image relatively to the BODY. Here is a method I use:

```
function getPosition(element)
{
var position = {x:-1, y:-1};

// no element //
if (element === null) return position;

// getting offset parent
var offsetParentNode = document.body; 

// calculating position //
position.x = 0;
position.y = 0;
var _parent = element;
while (_parent !== offsetParentNode && _parent !== document.body && _parent !== null)
{
    position.x += _parent.offsetLeft;   
    position.x -= _parent.scrollLeft;
    position.y += _parent.offsetTop;    
    position.y -= _parent.scrollTop;
    _parent = _parent.offsetParent;
}

if (offsetParentNode !== document.body && (_parent === document.body || _parent === null))
{
    position.x = -1;
    position.y = -1;
}

return position;
}
```